# Modify data from XML Request with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I try get data from RSS of a website. But i have some error

Sorry, my English is not good

My code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://tuhoc247.com/feed/",
dataType: "xml",
success: function (xml) {
  $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
    console.log("title      : " + $(this).find("title").text());
    console.log("link       : " + $(this).find("link").text());
    var $html = $(this).find('content\\:encoded').html()
    console.log($html.find('ul').text());
  });
},
error: function () {
  alert("An error occurred.");
}
});
```

But error: "$html.find is not function"

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
console.log($html.find('ul').text());
```

To :

```
console.log($($html).find('ul').text());
```